# Dataclass with metaclass registration

Tags: python, metaclass, python-3.8, python-dataclasses

I have a dataclass class A which can be inherited and used for creation of other classes. Everytime when my class A is inherited I would like to register the child class into the container. I wanted to solve it with metaclasses, but it doesn't work for me. Any help please?

```py
container = {}

class Meta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, *args, **kwargs):
        new_class = super().__new__(mcs, *args, **kwargs)

        if new_class.__name__ != 'A':
            container[new_class.__name__] = new_class

        return new_class


@metaclass
class MasterClass:
    parent


@metaclass
class A(MasterClass, metaclass=Meta):
    my_arg


@metaclass
class Child(A): # <-- this class I would like to register into child container
    my_next_arg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, but for using  a "@metaclass" when it should be "@dataclass" decorator, and creating some annotation on the fields, without which you will have a NameError exception.

So, if you do just this:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Any
container = {}

class Meta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, *args, **kwargs):
        new_class = super().__new__(mcs, *args, **kwargs)

        if new_class.__name__ != 'A':
            container[new_class.__name__] = new_class

        return new_class


@dataclass
class MasterClass:
    parent: Any


@dataclass
class A(MasterClass, metaclass=Meta):
    my_arg: Any


@dataclass
class Child(A): # <-- this class I would like to register into child container
    my_next_arg: Any
```

It will work as you expect, and `Child` will be registered in the 
container:

```py
In [5]: container                                                                                                                    
Out[5]: {'Child': __main__.Child}
```

Just note that since Python 3.6 you don't need to use a metaclass
for this pattern, as the `__init_subclass__` classmethod is called
on subclass creation, and can do just the same:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Any

container = {}

@dataclass
class MasterClass:
    parent: Any


@dataclass
class A(MasterClass):
    def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kw):
        super().__init_subclass__(*args, **kw)
        container[cls.__name__] = cls

    my_arg: Any


@dataclass
class Child(A): # <-- this class I would like to register into child container
    my_next_arg: Any
```

Comment: The solution with `__init_subclass__` method is exactly what I need in my case. Thank you.